# View React Native code as Java or Objective-C code

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native

I am wondering, if it is possible to translate React Native source code into Java/Objective-C representation of the same code and continue work on the project with those two languages. 
That would be helpful, if work has to be done on critical parts of the code or a particular module has not yet been implemented in React Native. 
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. React-Native uses a bridge to convert the objects to their native counterparts in runtime.

You can read [this article](https://tadeuzagallo.com/blog/react-native-bridge/) that explains the communication between native code and JavaScript.